# Where could I find, or what is a material that could be used with 30 GHz pulsed DC current to produce 30 GHz pulses of light?

Tags: optics, lasers

I need to produce pulses of light that turn on and off for equal intervals at 30 GHz. I know there are lasers that are capable of this frequency, so I need to know what materials they use to produce pulses of light at that frequency within those lasers. How could I search for them?

Comment: As you know the lasers, check the specs...